# my date format 12-2018 how to get name of month in php?

Tags: php

It is giving correct date but not the correct day value.Why..?

What I want day is the date for monday for the current week which can be generated on any day of the week. so what I did was, I'm taking the today's day and comparing with (Mon,Tue.... Sun) and respectively creating a timestamp using

Comment: `12-2018` is very ambiguous date. Is it December or 12th day of month? And not sure what you wish to get here. Can you share your code and example outputs?

Comment: i have try date('M-Y', strtotime('12-2018')); this but output is 01-1907 12th is month

Comment: "my date format 12-2018 how to get name of month in php?" if 12-2018 is the input, what is your expected output? your requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date("Y-m-d",strtotime("monday"));` to find out next Monday.
To find Monday from any day of the week you can try this-

```
$date="2018-08-01"; //any day of the week
$day=date("N",strtotime($date));
if($day>1){
    $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$date -1 week"));
}
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$date monday"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't sure what you really want but if you want current day date simply use getdate() function